# Prevent execution of two directive expressions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I've got this html

```
<nav ng-init="items = false">
    <ul class="main-items">
        <li><a ng-click="..."></a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="..."></a></li>
        ...
        <li><a ng-click="items = !items">More...</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="more-items" ng-show="items" doc-mousedown="$parent.items = false">
        <li><a ng-click="...">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="...">Item 2</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What this does:

1. `.main-items` are always visible and when **More...** is clicked it toggles the display of `more-items`.
2. The `doc-click` is my custom simple directive that listens for document *mousedown* which checks that mouse was being interacted **outside** of the element on which the directive is defined and executes the expression provided. In this case it hides `.more-items`.

### The problem

Clicking the **More...** link works and correctly shows the additional items, but when it is then clicked again, this element is outside of the element with directive so directive fires first and then also the `ngClick` on the **More...** link, which shows additional items instead of just hiding them...

I'm trying to resolve this, but I can't seem to come about this problem. I wanted to use `$event.preventDefault()` on the `docMousedown` but mousedown and click are two events that don't share event object. :(

**How would you suggest to solve this?**

### Working example

```js
DocDetectController.$inject = ["$scope", "$element", "$document"];

function DocDetectController($scope, $element, $document) {
  var el = $element[0];
  var self = this;
  
  $document.on("mousedown.docDetect", function(evt) {
    if (evt.target !== el && !$.contains(el, evt.target)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $scope.$apply(self.docDetect);
    }
  });
}

angular
  .module("Test", [])
  .directive("docDetect", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      controller: DocDetectController,
      controllerAs: "doc",
      scope: true,
      bindToController: {
        docDetect: "&"
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #000;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

nav.collapsed .more-items {
  display: none;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<section ng-app="Test">
  <nav ng-class="{ collapsed: collapse }" ng-init="collapse = true">
    <ul class="main-items">
      <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="collapse = !collapse">More...</a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <ul class="more-items" doc-detect="$parent.collapse = true">
      <li><a href="">More 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it an option to put an ID on the anchor tag and check against that ID in the mousedown directive? If that's OK, you can also add `doc-whitelist="some ids"` so you can reuse that elsewhere.

Comment: Share the code for `doc-mousedown` and if possible create a fiddle

Comment: @Satpal I've added a working example. Try clicking **More...** when additional items are being displayed.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, there is no way to identify whether is `evt.target` is __More__ anchor. Can you add a specific class? if so you can exclude based on it. Or redesign you app so that `more-items` is child of `More`

Comment: @Satpal. I've provided my own answer without any extra code. Just an `ng-switch` and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The simplest solution

is the one that changes behaviour of **More...** depending on `$scope.items` value.

#### HTML template

```
<nav ng-init="items = false">
    <ul class="main-items">
        <li><a ng-click="..."></a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="..."></a></li>
        ...
        <!-- THIS IS THE CHANGE -->
        <li ng-switch="!!items">
            <a ng-switch-when="false" ng-click="items = !items">More...</a>
            <a ng-switch-when="true" href="">More...</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="more-items" ng-show="items" doc-mousedown="$parent.items = false">
        <li><a ng-click="...">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="...">Item 2</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```js
DocDetectController.$inject = ["$scope", "$element", "$document"];

function DocDetectController($scope, $element, $document) {
  var el = $element[0];
  var self = this;
  
  $document.on("mousedown.docDetect", function(evt) {
    if (evt.target !== el && !$.contains(el, evt.target)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $scope.$apply(self.docDetect);
    }
  });
}

angular
  .module("Test", [])
  .directive("docDetect", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      controller: DocDetectController,
      controllerAs: "doc",
      scope: true,
      bindToController: {
        docDetect: "&"
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #000;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

nav.collapsed .more-items {
  display: none;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<section ng-app="Test">
  <nav ng-class="{ collapsed: collapse }" ng-init="collapse = true">
    <ul class="main-items">
      <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
      <li ng-switch="!!collapse">
        <a ng-switch-when="true" href="" ng-click="$parent.collapse = !$parent.collapse">More...</a>
        <a ng-switch-when="false" href="">More...</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <ul class="more-items" doc-detect="$parent.collapse = true">
      <li><a href="">More 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">More 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to do this you need to check the target for this solution 
 in your child event you just need to add a check where you will make sure that the if target is parent element don't trigger anything in that case you need to check the element from where it's being trigerred you can get those details in your event object.

Comment: It's not that straight forward. Toggle may not share the same parent as the element with the directive. In my case it does, but as this is a common directive that may not be the case. This is a common directive that is closing custom dropdowns, modeless windows etc... Check my updated question with a working example.